# Zepto Product Personalizer

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, product

I'm using Zepto Product Personalizer on the backend of my shopify website I'm building (not live yet) This app allows me to add customization options for users and some of these options add a price change to the product being customized by the app. I'm finding that when I add customization that trigger a price increase, it also changes the price of related products displayed at the bottom of my product page. When I click on a product from the related products to go to the individual product page, it shows the base price. Can anyone help or guide me to where I need to go to fix this?

I have reached out to shopify, they said it's a Zepto issue. I have looked into related product within my online store and haven't found a correlation. I have checked Zepto settings and have not found a correlation there either

Comment: Zepto Product Personalizer doesn't change the product price permanently. So, when you are going to a new product anywhere from your store, you will show the base price.